# Looking for info on the Ven. Mahasi Sayadaw tradition

Tags: vipassana, reference-request, mahasi-sayadaw

I have started practicing Vipassana meditation and seek information on the Mahasi Sayadaw tradition. Could anyone provide me with some sources for learning about and understanding this tradition? Thank you!

Comment: Ven. Yuttadhammo teaches from this tradition - https://www.youtube.com/user/yuttadhammo/featured

Comment: Check out [this website](http://www.yellowrobe.com/books/mahasi-sayadaw/237-books-by-mahasi-sayadaw.html) which has free books by Mahasi Sayadaw. Here you will find books on the Mahasi meditation method and lots of other great stuff. Also take a look at the [Resource Section](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help). As someone else mentioned Ven. Yuttadhammo teaches the Mahasi-method and you can find an overview of his videos [here](http://video.sirimangalo.org). Check out the meditation-section. If you have any more questions regarding the Mahasi-tradition let me know.

Comment: I've converted this to a wiki,  so feel free to post various resources in individual answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for reading material, here are some good resources:

- http://www.sirimangalo.org/teachings
- http://www.saraniya.com/page/ebooks/ebooks-mahasi-sayadaw.html
- http://www.yellowrobe.com/books/mahasi-sayadaw/237-books-by-mahasi-sayadaw.html

If you are looking to follow a course, it depends on where you are or where you can travel to.
If you are in Canada, checkout the courses page at [sirimangalo.org](http://www.sirimangalo.org/courses)
If you come to Asia, there are many choices. Here are a few:

- [Sri Lanka](http://meditation.lk/)
- [Myanmar](http://www.buddhanet.net/m_centre.htm)
- [Thailand](http://www.dharmaoverground.org/dharma-wiki/-/wiki/Main/Chom+Tong+Insight+Meditation+Center) (besides Wat Chom Tong, where Ajahn Tong is the abbot, there is also [Wat Ram Poeng](http://www.watrampoeng.net) and [Doi Suthep](http://www.fivethousandyears.org/) - same tradition, all have instruction in English)

Answer (score 0):

The Chom Tong tradition (linked in the answer above for Thailand already) also has a number of centers in Europe and around (incomplete list):

- [Dhammacari](http://vipassana-dhammacari.com) (Germany)
- [Tisarana](http://tisarana.cz) (Czech Republic)
- [Newman Meditation Center](http://en.metta.org.il) (Israel)

There are also teachers not attached to a specific center, giving courses at various places (again, very incomplete list):

- [Martin Pack](http://www.risingfalling.org) (UK, Austria, Thailand)